# Footer not staying at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I got my footer to stay at the bottom of my page [here](http://www.pattersoncode.ca), but I did something, don't know what, and now it's below the content. I've tried changing the min-height values of the wrapper, but it didn't do a thing.

Footer code:

```
<div id='footer'>&copy; Copyright 2013 Austen Patterson. All Rights Reserved.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Footer style:

```
#footer {
margin-right: 10%;
min-width: 100%;
color: #4bb3e6;
text-align: right;
}
```

Body/Wrapper style:

```
body {
    background:url("http://pattersoncode.ca/incls/pw_pattern.png");
    color: black;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Verdana, sans-serif";
    min-width: 94%;
    min-height: 95%;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
#wrapper {

    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 0.25s; 
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.25s; 
    -o-animation: fadein 0.25s;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 95%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
position:absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

to your footer selector.

Comment: Genius! Thanks :D Don't know why it moved but glad you helped me fix it <3

Comment: This is bad, it will fail if the content exceeds the viewport.. better take a look at Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using `position: absolute`. As of time of writing, your page breaks when you have too much content on the page (enough content for a scrollbar). I assume you always want the footer below the content.

In order to make sure your body's `min-height` styling works, add:

```
html { height: 100% }
```

Additionally, to make sure your footer always appears below the content, add

```
body {
    margin: 0; //remove default margin. you may not need
               //this, but it will prevent problems with
               //the body being too big
    min-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; //making sure padding works with 100% sizing.
    padding-bottom: 40px; //just enough for your footer
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This will remove your footer from the flow of the page, *but that's OK*, since we have allocated a 40px space at the bottom of the page for it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #4BB3E6;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `positon:fixed`, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/VDfcC/

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:10;
    margin-right: 10%;
    min-width: 100%;
    color: #4bb3e6;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well maybe it's because you have a min-height of 95%. If not, you can try:

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```